# How to detect loop-aes encrypted disk/ partition

Tags: cryptography

I'm working on loop-aes disk decrytion, there are 2 main jobs:

1. Detection
2. Decryption

Regarding to #1, the approach is to base on the header of encrypted drives, looking for a pattern that is same for every loop-aes encrypted drives -> however this is failed since the header is changed constantly depends on the gpg key.

I tried googling however there is rarely topic to detect loop-aes. Just ask if anyone got some ideas that could help me?

Thank and have a good day!

Comment: What is a "loop-aes encrypted drive"?

Comment: @JamesKPolk here is the loop-aes encryption software https://sourceforge.net/projects/loop-aes/

Basically loop-aes supports to encrypt both file and disk/ partition.

Sorry to make you confuse, the "drive" here mean "disk/ parttition". I will update the title